# VBA doesn't divide local variable (Error 6 overflow)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to program a simple z-test but my code gives an error when calculating the Z-score with this code: `Z = (P1 - P2) / SD;` does anyone know why? The error that comes up is an overflow (error 6)

Here's the full code:

```
Sub ChiSquare()

    Total_Groep_1 = Application.Sum(Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)))
    Total_Groep_2 = Application.Sum(Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)))


    For i = 5 To Range("C4").End(xlDown)
                Dim P1 As Double
    P1 = Cells(i, 3) / Total_Groep_1
    Cells(i, 4) = P1

    Dim P2 As Double
    P2 = Cells(i, 5) / Total_Groep_2
    Cells(i, 6) = P2

    Dim SD As Double
    SD = Sqr((P1 * (1 - P1) / Total_Groep_1) + (P2 * (1 - P2) / Total_Groep_2))
    Cells(i, 7) = SD

    Dim Z As Double
    Z = (P1 - P2) / SD
    Cells(i, 8) = Z

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Why are you returning an array to SD? You can't divide a number by an array like that.

Comment: I didn't before and it didn't work then: I was trying the array as a solution

Comment: The error says "overloop" (in Dutch) which in English I think is Overflow

Comment: Are your variables declared anywhere, or is this the whole code? Also -- what line is triggering the error?

Comment: I declared them just now; I didn't before. It still gives an error. The line 'Z=(P1-P2)/SD' produces the error

Comment: Shouldn't it be For i = 5 To Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row?

Comment: Yes! That's it! I looped it till a range before, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The loop that I made didn't go to a number but to a range. It works now I changed that.

Comment: The loop did go to a number -- just not the number you intended. What must have been the case is that the cell contained a number which was so big that when you tried to loop that far you got outside of your data range and when your formula for `SD` evaluated to 0 on the blank cells. It does seem odd that *overflow* rather than *division by 0* was the error.

Comment: Also, you should declare i as a Long, because you could have more than 65K rows of data.